# How to Query Remote Database with Huge Where Clause from Local Database

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I am populating a table in a local database (localdb, SQL Server) with data pulled from a remote database (remotedb, Oracle).

The remote database is across the internets, and of course, local database is local to my db server.

I need to pull data from remotedb, and in order to pull the data from remotedb, I need to only pull data from specific key values (e.g. the user_id field on a table on remotedb).

The set of keys is large, approx. 10,000.

Oh, by the way, remotedb is read-only access, and I don't have access to things like imp/exp or batch or access to the server (it is with an outside vendor).

Currently, I am using a query like this:

```
SELECT
   <my data>
FROM
   <remotedb>.<remote_table> join <remotedb>.<remote_table> ...
WHERE
   <remotedb>.<remote_table>.<remote_field> in
   ( <select that returns my 20,000 IDs> )
```

This seems like a brute force solution to me, but I can't think of any other way to do it.

Has anyone out there solved this problem?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable approach.  Is there something demonstably wrong with it?  For example, is the optimizer choosing the wrong driving site, forcing too much data to be fetched from the remote database to do the joins locally rather than simply shipping the 20,000 IDs to the remote database and letting the remote database do the joins?  Also, you've tagged this for both SQL Server and Oracle-- which database are you using?

Comment: would it be possible to send your key to a procedure on remotedb?

Comment: @Justin - I've updated the question, remote is oracle, and local is sql server.

Comment: @bummi I thought of somehow shipping the 20k ID values over to a stored proc, but I don't have any proc, nor the ability to create a proc, on the other end.  In addition, I am not sure how this would differ?

Comment: @Justing All the joins are remotedb tables with remotedb tables, so I am expecting the join to happen on the oracle side.  Do you think I should tear it down in sql server side to see what the optimizer is doing?  I guess I just expected it to "tunnel" the query over to oracle before attempting to do anything.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your statement correctly, we had a similar issue with this at a past company and it created a performance hit.  Unless the vendor can pull all the information for you beforehand and you perform a query off that, I don't see another way around it.

Comment: I was having similar thoughts last night, however, the vendor database is refreshed daily, and I am not sure if they could pull the 20k IDs from our database (us opening access for them, etc.)

Comment: Can they pull all the information you need from their system before hand in a view, then you can do the join once to the view?